# Object.clone in method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any native method `Object.clone` in modern browsers ? which is act same like `jQuery.extend`

```
TypeError: Object.clone is not a function
```

`Object.create` not giving result as `jQuery.extend` . I don't want to include jQuery lib for clone my object

```
var m = { a: 10 };
var x = Object.create( m );

m.a = 99;
x.b = 10;

console.log( m , x );
```

my expected result is `{ a:99 } { b:10, a:10 }` but it gives `{ a:99 } { b:10, a:99 }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @undefined JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObject)) gives expected result! there no native method in modern browser for this .right ?

Comment: No, there is no such method yet, maybe in ECMAScript 6.